# Check if Google Maps App is installed in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I am trying to figure out how to handle the result of this code to see if Google Maps is installed in the app.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]];
```

I am creating a `UIAlertView` with the option in there and if it is or isn't I wish to give the user different options.

How do I take the result of the code above and turn it into a BOOLEAN?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The result is already of [`canOpenURL:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW50) a boolean:

```
BOOL canHandle = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps:"]];

if (canHandle) {
   // Google maps installed
} else {
   // Use Apple maps?
}
```

Comment: Cool that makes sense now - never saw it like that:-)

Comment: it returns false and google map is already there in iphone 
is there any other solution for ios9???

Comment: You need to add `comgooglemaps://` to you list of app url scheme that you will call in iOS 9. Just add the URLs your will be call to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your apps `info.plist`

Comment: I have add comgooglemaps:// in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes (plist file). But still it’s  giving wrong result. Google map available in my iPhone but it’s returning false

Comment: @PatelJigar Have you got any solution? I am facing same problem!

Comment: u just have to add  LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in info.plist and above code will run perfactly @keyurbhalodiya

Comment: yes I just written comgooglemaps in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes info.plist file and check with if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps:"]])  it's work for me now.

Comment: In iOS9.0 and above we have to remove "//" from "comgooglemaps://".

Comment: You can also read the [URL scheme manual](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme)

Comment: what will happen if google maps is not installed and even apple maps is removed (for ios 10+)??

Comment: Nothing. But you might want to add a check of this.

Answer (score 5):

Above for iOS 9.0

**Step 1.** Add **comgooglemaps** in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in your apps info.plist

**Step 2.**

```
BOOL isGoogleMap = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]];
UIAlertView *alert;

if(isGoogleMap)
{
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
             initWithTitle:@"Get Directions"
             message:@"Show Map"
             delegate:self
             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
             otherButtonTitles:@"View in Apple Maps", @"View in Google Maps", nil];
}
else
{
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
             initWithTitle:@"Get Directions"
             message:@"Show Map"
             delegate:self
             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
             otherButtonTitles:@"View in Apple Maps", nil];
}
alert.tag = 1010;
[alert show];
```