# Implementing UIActivity subclass for Facebook Messenger iPhone App?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

Hello I'm implementing different ways in my project to share some TEXT to other Chat Applications, such as: Whatsapp, Line and WeChat.

I have no problem to implement this UIActivity subclass using following libs:

- Whatsapp (https://github.com/jberlana/JBWhatsAppActivity)
- Line (https://github.com/OopsMouse/LINEActivity)
- WeChat (https://github.com/iDay/WeixinActivity)

I realise all these Apps has internal URI protocol to communicate with them from my application:

> whatsapp://send?text=SAMPLE_TEXT
>
> line://msg/text/SAMPLE_TEXT

Anyone knows the way to connect to Facebook Messenger iPhone App to share some text, at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20320386/1953538) - not sure whether it's official API by facebook - couldn't find any docs on it.