# Facebook Messenger App Link [iOS]

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I'm creating an iOS application where I'd like to integrate Facebook Messenger for users to message each other. I've tried deeplinking via fb-messenger://user-thread/{user-id}, which works as intended. When I open the URL via my app, it switches over to Facebook Messenger. However, as this type of link seems undocumented by Facebook, I'd rather not risk using it as they might change it at any given time.

I've then looked into Facebook App Links, but as they're very few examples of how to actually use it, I'm not completely sure how to use it for a simple case of switching from my own app to messenger with a user-id as a parameter.

Any comments on this matter will be much appreciated.

Comment: The Facebook app and Messenger app doesn't support App links. And there is no documented way to interact with either of them so anything you do may break at any second

Comment: Seems odd - how do you know this?

Comment: I work at Facebook

Comment: Should have checked your bio. Thanks.
I've considered using the Facebook Message Dialog. However, it doesn't seem like there's any way to set a recipient as a parameter. Do you know of any alternatives related to FB Messenger that might solve my problem?

Comment: No, there is nothing else then the Message Dialog

Comment: Your comments here would make a reasonable answer, @WizKid

Comment: Hi WizKid,
I am looking to send some link over Facebook Messenger app from my mobile website on Chrome Browser on my mobile. 
I am using the facebook messenger's custom URI Scheme fb-messenger://share. I saw this option on the the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467445/custom-uri-schemes-for-the-facebook-messenger?rq=1
I used the full url as:
fb-messenger://share?ShareType=ShareType.regular&share_story_url=<URL>
I tried multiple options for share, as mentiond in the link above, but nothing works. It tries to open the app and closes.
Regards, Manik Mittal