# Deep linking to Facebook Messenger

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking

From a lot of searching, I found that using `fb-messenger://user-thread/ID` can be used to deep link to Messenger and open the existing thread with the passed in FB ID or start a new thread if not existent.

It pops over to Messenger and opens a thread, but the thread is with `Facebook User` and doesn't actually send. See image below. Clicking Facebook User in the header goes to a detail view with the correct user's image and name.

How do I make this work correctly?

[image]

Comment: Please keep in mind that Facebook always changes their schemes from time to time, so make sure you don't give it a critical part in your system.

Comment: Hey Chris, I now this is an old post, but did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As [WizKid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101130/wizkid) (FB Employee) said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285373/facebook-messenger-app-link-ios#comment43038754_27285373):

> ...there is no documented way to interact with ... [Messenger] so anything
>   you do may break at any second.

So with that in mind, it sounds like `fb-messenger://user-thread/ID` has been deprecated. That being said, I decompiled the Facebook Android APK and found a line:

```
return Uri.parse((new StringBuilder("fb-messenger://user/")).append(Uri.encode(s)).toString());
```

So from what I can see, it looks like `fb-messenger://user-thread/ID` has been replaced with `fb-messenger://user/ID`

There's also a line thats:

```
return Uri.parse((new StringBuilder("fb-messenger://thread/")).append(Uri.encode(s)).toString());
```

So `fb-messenger://thread/ID` may be valid too. ID could be a user or thread ID, I didn't dig deep enough to find out.

EDIT:
Current Facebook URL is `fb-messenger-public://user-thread/ID`

Comment: Thanks for digging around to provide a thorough answer. Probably not worth it to embed one of these URLs into a production app and risk it breaking at anytime. It's unfortunate that this isn't more open to 3rd party use. Oh well

Comment: Happy to help, sorry I couldn't give you the answer you were hoping for. If you're building a native app, you may be able to call the app using the new iOS SDK https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/ios

Comment: Odd.  I found that the user-thread version is the only one that opened the actual conversation for me, i.e. `fb-messenger://user-thread/{user_id}` where `user_id` is a numeric id.   The `fb-messenger//user/...` version opened messenger but not the conversation.  I couldn't get any user or thread id to work with the `fb-messenger://thread/...` form.  Desktop and mobile browser equivalents for the user conversation look like `https://www.facebook.com/messages/{user_id}` or `https://m.facebook.com/messages/read/?fbid={user_id}`

Comment: Current Facebook URL is ```fb-messenger-public://user-thread/ID```

Comment: in android every time display facebook user not a correct user account Uri.parse((new StringBuilder("fb-messenger://user/")).append(Uri.encode(use‌​r-id)).toString());

Comment: This doesn't work for me as of January 2018. Just links to an empty conversation in messenger.

Answer (score 26):

Sorry to bring this back from the dead, but it seems that Facebook Messenger has incorporated Universal Links to quick open the Messenger app.

```
m.me/$USERNAME
```

for example: http://m.me/zuck will universally link you to message Zuckerberg.

I played with a couple params, but nothing seemed to prefill the message.

Comment: Anyone know a way of using this with Facebook user IDs instead of usernames? I'm getting "Username was not found" when using this with Facebook IDs :(

Answer (score 3):

All of this has changed. Facebook released short links to connect with a brand or user's Messenger profile. The way to direct link is http://m.me/PROFILE or `PAGE_NAME`

If you're building bots, you can also pass in a referral parameter. I've written a bunch about this [linking in to Messenger conversations](https://medium.com/@michael_at_message/lets-keep-talking-more-ways-to-drive-facebook-messenger-bot-usage-4ddeb0cec6a0#.bqsgdz8ci).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to jump to code directly, here it is:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://m.me/%ld", USER_ID]];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `fb-messenger-public://user-thread/<ID>`
I got my `ID` from the recipient ID in the facebook messenger web hook payload. e.g.

```
{
    "object": "page",
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "1163189980393936",
            "time": 1500325170682,
            "messaging": [
                {
                    "sender": {
                        "id": ""
                    },
                    "recipient": {
                        "id": "ID"
                    },
                    "timestamp": 1500325170640,
                    "message": {
                        "mid": "mid.$cAAQh6kd9svBjg56V0FdUllNamImF",
                        "seq": 2888,
                        "text": "..."
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```