# How can I launch facebook messenger with to enable user to user chat

Tags: react-native, facebook-messenger

Users log into my app through the facebook sdk. If one user clicks on another user I'd like to enable them to chat via facebook messenger. I can launch messenger from my app, but is there a way to launch into the chat screen with a specific user.

Comment: Does Facebook have no documentation about react or messenger at all?

Comment: Facebook does have quite a lot of documentation about react and messanger. So far I can only find documentation about how to create a facebook chat bot, not what I want, and how to launch facebook messenger  with https://github.com/fiber-god/react-native-app-link no quite what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open a conversation in Messenger with deep links:

- `http://m.me/{user_name}` <- this is official link for Messenger. You'll need to ask user for his Messenger's username.
- `fb-messenger://user/{user_id}` <- this link is not documented, so it can break any time ([Deep linking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32060864/1814524)). `user_id` probably is the Facebook User Id, so it will be easier to obtain, however you'll need to ask for `user_profile` permission to get user id ([Messenger Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/permissions/))