# Facebook Messenger Platform API Live Person

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Is there a way to delegate the current conversation that a Messenger Platform bot is having to another person through the API? I could not find anything in the documentation.

If no, what's the best way to handle the use case where a person asks the bot to talk to a live person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to send message from one user to another, both user needs to be signed in to your bot, then User A needs to specify to which user he'd like to send a message, after that bot can send message to User B, because you know User A and User B Messenger IDs.

Sending messages to not signed in users is not possible.

Comment: That's the idea. There's a current user that's talking to the bot, and live persons signed in who can assist the user if live support is requested. My question is, how can I connect the live person with the customer through the API?

Comment: If you want Messenger-to-Messenger conversation, you need to resend each message user is sending. You need to identify if message was sent to another user or to bot. You could assume that all messages will be sent to another user and conversation would be cancelled through menu, or user would need to click Reply action after each bot's message to send next message.

Comment: That's a decent workaround that could work but I was wondering whether It was possible to make a direct connection. I guess not.

Comment: Check out my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47294061/1814524). I think this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the handover protocol to pass thread control to the page inbox, where a live person can respond.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol/pass-thread-control