# Communicating with Facebook Messenger with API / Deeplink

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-messenger

I have an app which will, at some point, require Facebook Messenger to scan QR to connect with a bot.

I found two ways to scan a QR with messenger so far:

**1-) Launch messenger and go to "People" tab and press "Scan QR" -> Scan the code**

**2-) Launch messenger, open camera, hold down to screen until circle appears -> Scan the code**

What I want to do is to reduce the steps required to scan a QR code.

I couldn't see any proper solution by going through the Facebook Android SDK & Messenger Platform docs.

So my questions are:

**1-) Is there any way to at least start the messenger with QR code reader on through deep link or with any official API ?**

**2-) Is there any other way to scan Facebook specific QR's ( circle ones ) outside of Messenger and launch messenger as a result ? ( launch a bot chat on Messenger with QR result )**

P.S.: I know that deep links may deprecate / change without notice. [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32060864/1830137) also states it, but when I check, I see [WizKid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101130/wizkid)'s [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285373/facebook-messenger-app-link-ios#comment43038754_27285373) is from 2014. I'm asking this question to learn possible ways and if they added any official way to communicate with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want for it to be scanned with any reader, you can generate your own QR pointing to: `https://m.me/{page_name}`.

> m.me is a shortened URL service operated by Facebook that redirects users to a person, page, or bot in Messenger. You can use them on your website, email newsletters, and more.
>
> When a user starts a new conversation or continues an existing conversation with your bot via an m.me link, the following message will appear in the conversation: "You have entered this conversation by following a link. We've let PAGE_NAME know you're here."
>
> The format of the link is http://m.me/{PAGE_NAME}, where PAGE_NAME is the handle of the Facebook page the bot is linked to.

This will in fact deep link into a conversation with your bot.

Additional documentation for this is available in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links

Comment: Thanks, I can use regular QR's as last resort, my main effort for the second question is to figure out if it's possible to scan Messenger style QR's ( circle ones ) via any 3rd party scanner.