# Custom URI Scheme Facebook breaks

Tags: facebook, uri, url-scheme

So regarding [this Post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467445/custom-uri-schemes-for-the-facebook-messenger) it should be possible to link via

```
fb-messenger://user/%s
```

to Facebook Messenger and open the "chat window" with %s. Where %s is FBid I assume? This does not work for me. What I have is FBid of friends who use the App and I want to add possibility, that if I click on a friend the chat window in Messenger with this Friend opens. Should be possible with URI Schemes, right?

Comment: There is no supported way to open messenger with a specific user

Comment: really? thats a great pity :-( okay thanks

Comment: and open their profile in normal FB-App?

Comment: Not possible that either