# Sending URL using Facebook messenger from my Mobile Website

Tags: facebook, share, messenger

I am looking to send some link over Facebook Messenger app from my mobile website on Chrome Browser on my mobile. I am using the facebook messenger's custom URI Scheme fb-messenger://share. I saw this option on the the following link: [Custom URI Schemes for the Facebook Messenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467445/custom-uri-schemes-for-the-facebook-messenger?rq=1) I used the full url as: fb-messenger://share?ShareType=ShareType.regular&share_story_url= I tried multiple options for share, as mentiond in the link above, but nothing works. It tries to open the app and closes.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it by adding the following link to your page:

```
<a href="fb-messenger://share?link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww..."></a>
```

I don't know what else you can pass except for the `link`, maybe a user ID with `to` (probably the same params as described in the [dialog method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog)

Comment: Thank a lot Guillaume. It really helped.

Comment: @ManikMittal maybe you could accept the answer then ;)

Comment: Tried this in Gmail but it did not work. Gmail removes this hyperlink.

Comment: @SagarVimal I guess you need to take this issue with Gmail then ;)

Comment: Here is just open messenger app not sending any message

Comment: By the way, you can put anything in "link". even text.

Answer (score 1):

i'm facing same issue and this is not working in ios devices.
In android devices its working fine.

I have used this one:
fb-messenger://share?link=" + smsString; (smsString is var)