# SMS uri scheme not working with third party SMS apps

Tags: url-scheme

The universal uri scheme `sms:` only worked when the phone's default sms app is the system messaging app. When it's set to third party apps liks FB Messenger / Truecaller, it doesnt work. Has anyone faces this issue & is there any workaround for it? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom URI Schemes for the Facebook Messenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467445/custom-uri-schemes-for-the-facebook-messenger)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it doesn't really address my issue. Ultimately, I need to be able to trigger sms send through a universally recognized uri scheme. Otherwise, for each possible third party apps, I will need to integrate the app-specific deeplink, doesnt seem scalable.

I wonder if we can force open the system messaging app even when the default app set is other third party app @@

Comment: You could always inform the user that not a valid SMS app is found (and let him pick the app to be used ?)

Comment: @Luuk Im using React Native, I don't see there's anything that could detect whether there's a valid SMS app. And I was hoping to auto populate the receiver phone number and sms message. When using `sms:` , it works for default sms app but when user choose 3rd party sms app, it no longer work.