# Facebook Messenger Compose Predefined Message

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme

I am using  fb-messenger://compose to open Facebook Messenger Composer, but I can't manage to put predefined message into the composer.

Does somebody know the parameters?

Comment: There's a few Stack Overflow threads that already address this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467445/custom-uri-schemes-for-the-facebook-messenger

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059001/custom-url-to-launch-facebook-messenger-on-ios (you may need to use the Facebook SDK)

Comment: I'm trying the same thing.have you manage to post a predefined message?

Comment: Nope. We couldn't solve it. FB changed the URL Schemes :(

Comment: @RobertKeus where can I find new url schemes ?

Comment: How have u done that? i m struggling

Comment: The new schemes use Pasteboards.  I answered a similar question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689056/compose-a-message-with-predefined-link-attached-from-ios-app-into-facebook-messe/36978527#36978527

Answer (score 9):

You should send content via messenger using FBSDKShareKit.

Import FBSDKShareKit

```
#import <FBSDKShareKit.h>
```

Create content and share

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.url.com"];
content.contentTitle = @"My link!";
content.contentDescription = @"Check out my link!";

[FBSDKMessageDialog showWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

You also need to conform your controller to the FBSDKSharingDelegate

```
#pragma mark - FBSDKSharingDelegate

- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results {

}

- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

}

- (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer {

}
```

Available contents are:

- FBSDKShareLinkContent
- FBSDKSharePhotoContent
- FBSDKShareVideoContent

Comment: Thanks dude i have being fighting with the Messenger SDK for a few days. Didn't think to user the message dialog! sweet