# How to send user to Facebook page on button click (Facebook messenger)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I created a game with sprite builder/cocos2d.

How can I send a user to a Facebook Messenger page on button click?

Comment: What did you already try?

Answer (score 0):

Your button's action needs to open a custom URL that will launch Messenger. The format is `fb-messenger://user-thread/{user-id}.` See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20320386).

Comment: so i write this fb-messenger://user-thread/{user-id}. in my -(void)button{} ?

Comment: You construct the URL by substituting the user-id for the `{user-id}` bit, then open the URL. That'll launch Messenger.