# FB-Messenger share url is not working for IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, messenger

[image]

I want to share website URL from my website to fb messenger. For that, I am using **fb-messenger://share/?link=PageUrl** syntax in href. It's working fine when shared from android but not sharing URL when shared from IOS. Is there any specific syntax for ios or am I missing something.
As shown in image whenever I share url from website to messenger it opens messenger app and after sending it gives error.

```
<a class="btn-social" href="fb-messenger://share/?link=pageurl&app_id=******" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-messenger"></i></a>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom URL to launch Facebook Messenger on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059001/custom-url-to-launch-facebook-messenger-on-ios)

Comment: May be  `fb-messenger://` is not supported in Safari, the browser which runs  on iOS ? Just write a simple HTML-page containing your link and test if this works iOS and Safari.

Comment: I tried using chrome instead of safari but it's still not working.